# Javascript object id field not being passed to event handler

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a react app containing two components, Counters and Counter, where the state object of the Counters component contains an array of objects with each representing a Counter.

In the actual jsx code for the Counters component, the items in the counters array is being rendered with each containing a delete button where each individual counter can be deleted.Right now, I have an arrow function to handle the delete which is set as an property in the Counter tags being rendered. Within the Counter component, there is an onCLick event in the delete button which takes as a paramerter the id of the Counter that was clicked.

For some reason, the delete is not working and when I console log the id of the Counter that has been clicked on, undefined is printed. **What could be causing the id property not to be read from the Counter component?**

***The relevant code is below:***

**Counter component:**

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.value
  };


  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleIncrement({ id: 1 })}
          className="btn btn-sercondary btn-sm"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}
          className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Counters Component:**

```
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 4 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]
  };

  handleDelete = counterId => {
    console.log("Event Handler Called", counterId);
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId);
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
          <Counter
            key={counter.id}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
            value={counter.value}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass prop `id` to `Couter` in the render function of component `Couters` since the button need it `<button onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}` ;

See here

```
<Counter
   id={counter.id}
   key={counter.id}
   onDelete={this.handleDelete}
   value={counter.value}
/>
```

Alternatively, you can do this

```
<Counter
   key={counter.id}
   onDelete={() => this.handleDelete(counter.id)}
   value={counter.value}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

You should use `this.props.key` inside the delete method in Component class instead of `this.props.id`.